# UIProgressView-like in WatchKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, uiprogressview

I have my app containing `UIProgressView`. One day I want to build its extension on `WatchKit` and want `UIProgressView` on that too, but there is no such a thing on the object library. What could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such library present over there, but you can use array of images to illustrate the progress view like animation. Refer this,this may help. [Github Link](https://github.com/mobitar/Starburst)

Comment: will have a look at that stuff. Thank you!